# Remove "(UNREGISTRED)" string from window title of Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, text-editor

##### I'm new to sublime text3 I am getting like that? how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Hey, man! You're pranking...

Comment: No, sir! I am not pranking..!

Comment: Excuse me. See my answer.

Comment: yeah I saw but it is paid (99$) , is there any other option to remove that ?

Comment: Yep! Even, more than one. Keep it "as is". Choose another free of charge editor.

Comment: yeah sure, sir!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select `Help` > `Purchase License` menu.